# Como pasar una funcion PHP a un código javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código en Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#caja_busqueda', function(){

    var valor = $(this).val();

    if (valor != "") {
        buscar_datos(valor);
    }else{
        buscar_datos();
    }
});
```

En "var valor" deseo agregarle una función PHP y/o Ajax, que me permita tomar una columna de una tabla desde mysql, para luego mostrar como contenido de un select los datos tomados de la columna.
Cual o como debiese ser la función en si?

Comment: no caigas en las malas practicas, de una vez te dire que no intentes mezclar javascript con PHP, porque solo te traera dolores de cabeza y bajones de seguridad muy graves luego, tu pregunta es sobre como pasar algo que no haz intentado investigar hacia PHP, estas preguntando codigo que no tienes o posees ni tampoco muestras que haz intentado del lado del PHP, porque PHP es el que hace esas cosas, NO Javascript.

Comment: Estimado, tengo levantada una pagina donde muestro una tabla que se extrae desde mysql con PHP, el codigo que muestro, esta en javascript y me falta hacer una funcion que se conecte con la BD, tome una columna de la tabla, y al tomar los datos, los pueda mostrar en un select, para luego usarlos como filtro de la tabla. Saludos

Comment: ¿La pregunta tiene que ver con [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371809/ayuda-con-variable-select-en-html) o [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371949/como-mostrar-opcion-seleccionable-una-columna-de-una-tabla-extraida-de-mysql) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372038/como-generar-enlace-desde-una-columna-de-una-tabla-extra%c3%adda-de-mysql)? En lugar de hacer múltiples preguntas, sé muy claro y específico con lo que necesitas, solo así podrás solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Para esto lo más recomendable es usar Ajax, que te permite comunicar entre cliente (JS) y servidor (PHP), enviando y/o recibiendo datos entre uno y otro de forma elegante (sin necesidad de recargar la página) y segura..

Comment: Y como seria el metodo o funcion de ajax para llamar a una columna especifica? Gracias

Comment: Aquí mismo hay varias respuestas que explican paso a paso cómo hacer funcionar un código JS/PHP usando Ajax. Desde JS en el parámetro `data` puedes mandar lo que quieras, el servidor recibe y procesa los datos que hayas enviado y los devuelve, los recibes en Ajax y los muestras en el cliente sin tener que recargar la página. Es así como funciona. Partiendo de eso, puedes hacer operaciones más complejas con suma facilidad. Revisa las preguntas del sitio, hay varias con buenas respuestas. Y si tienes una duda en concreto puedes preguntar indicando dicha duda concreta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, esto no es dificil, suponiendo que estas usando OOP lo unico que tienes que hacer es una funcion publica en alguna clase para que obtenga las opciones de seleccion de la base de datos y luego las inserte al HTML. No necesitas Javascript ni ajax para esto. Por ejemplo:

**php**

```
public function getData()
{
   $conn = $this->conn();
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table`");
   $stmt->execute();
   $array = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $stmt->close();
   $this->disconn();
   return ($array);
}
//Obtener arreglo
$data = getData();
```

**html**

```
   <select>
      <option selected>Selecciona un valor...</option>
      <?php foreach ($data as $value) : ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $value['valor']; ?>"><?php echo $value['valor']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
```

Tambien lo puedes hacer con Jquery! Por ejemplo:

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var html = "";
   $('#table td').each(function(){
         html += "<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>";
   });
   var select = $('select');
   select.html(html);
});
```

**Html**

```
<select id="select"></select>
<br><br>
<table id="table" border 2>
   <tr><td>Option 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Option 2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Option 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Option 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Y no existe un metodo o funcion, que permita agregar al codigo que muestro una columna de la tabla? Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Es confuso lo que me preguntas, quieres agregar una columna a la tabla de la base de datos o dependiendo de la seleccion agregar una tabla al html con los datos de la base de datos? son cosas distintas, amigo.

Comment: Quiero tomar una columna especifica de una tabla (la cual es mostrada por HTML y extraída de Mysql con php), y que los datos de la columna sean el contenido de un select en html. Lo que me falta y no entiendo, cual es el metodo o funcion, que necesito para sacar la columna y agregar eso en el código que muestro.

Comment: Ahhh ok! ya te entendi. Si, puedes usar la funcion `.each()` de jquery para tomar los valores de la tabla y luego modificar el <select> que deseas.

Comment: Y en este caso, en la variable "valor", como debiese cambiar el "(this).val()"? o debería crear una nueva condición?

Comment: te lo agrego a la respuesta original como sugerencia de @BetaM

Comment: También existe Vue ;-) para precisamente esto